# MySQL 5 Filter duplicates by one column only

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql 5, because gcloud only supports that...

I'm trying to filter out tags with a duplicate *text* column from a query, and found one way to do so using ROW_NUMBER() and an OVER() clause to pick the first (by id) tag of tags with duplicate text, but am getting a syntax error because over doesn't exist in mysql 5.

```
SELECT 
  c.*,
  CONCAT('[',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"id":',
      t.id,
      ', "company_id":',
      t.company_id,
      ', "client_id":',
      t.client_id,
      ', "user_id":',
      t.user_id,
      ', "text":"',
      t.text,
      '", "color":"',
      t.color,
    '"}')
  ORDER BY t.id),
  ']') AS tags
FROM
  company_users AS cu
    LEFT JOIN
  companies AS c ON cu.company_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `text` ORDER BY `id` ASC) AS tagnum
    FROM client_tags AS t
  ) t ON c.id = t.company_id AND tagnum = 1
WHERE
  # temp
  cu.user_id = 1
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Is there something else I could use? I don't even know if this method would work because I can't run it.

Comment: There's a user variables based solution [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=1098), sorry don't have time to write up an answer. mysql5 covers such broad range of implementations, suggest always using 5.7 as the two number together correspond to the major version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to get the match that has the smallest `id`:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM company_users cu LEFT JOIN
     companies c
     ON cu.company_id = c.id LEFT JOIN
     client_tags t
     ON t.company_id = c.id AND
        t.id = (SELECT MIN(t2.id)
                FROM client_tags t2
                WHERE t2.text = t.text
               )
WHERE cu.user_id = 1
```

Note that the correlated subquery needs to go in the `ON` clause, because this is a `LEFT JOIN`.